# use jQuery to find images loaded to the dom after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

am working with a page that utilizes 3rd party vendors to place images onto the page after the DOM loads.

I am developing a bookmarklet script that will allow a in-house user to click on any image on the site, and retrieve it's `id` and `src`. The script works well on test pages containing just an image loaded with the initial document, but pages that have imagery contained within iframes, or divs loaded after the initial page load do not alert as expected.

```
//$(window).load(function()
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").css('cursor', 'crosshair');
    $("img").click(function(){
      var altimg = $(this).attr('alt');
      var srcimg = $(this).attr('src');
    alert('ID is: '+ altimg+ '\n SRC: '+ srcimg);
  });
});
```

Is there a better way to review the dom with a bookmarklet placed script on a previously loaded page? I wasn't sure if `document.ready` or `window.load` was the appropriate method hence why one is commented out and both are in the code.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPwjh/)

Comment: You can't act on iframe. It's a matter of security. If you want to act on iframe you have to put the javascript within the iframe.

Comment: what about divs loaded to the dom after page load?

Comment: You have ton bind the events just after you append the divs to the dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for handling images loaded dynamically (regarding iframes I believe it won't work).

Using **event delegation**:

```
$(document).on("click","img",function(){
      var altimg = $(this).attr('alt');
      var srcimg = $(this).attr('src');
    alert('ID is: '+ altimg+ '\n SRC: '+ srcimg);
  });
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPwjh/1/)

Comment: I was still experiencing difficulties with this on sites, but I discovered I just need to rework my bookmarklet script. Seems to function now. Thanks